# Yii2: Upload image to MongoDB (Blob, Base64, Binary)

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to store an image in my MongoDB using a form, but I want to store the whole image into my database and not upload it to the server, and then store the image path in the database.

Is there any way I can encode it to a blob, Base64 or even Binary?
And no, the way described here (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/622/upload-files-in-yii2-with-mongodb-and-gridfs/) is not the way I'm looking to do it.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For images up to 16MB you can use the type MongoBinData.

Something like:

```
// get temporary filename from form model
$tmpname = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file')->tempName;

// create new Active Record
$imageModel = new UploadedImage; 

// set attribute using a new MongoBinData object
// the object is created using $tmpname contents
$imageModel->contents = new MongoBinData(
                         file_get_contents($tmpname),
                         MongoBinData::GENERIC);
```

You may also want to check some php.ini parameters for any restrictions to upload size and maximum PHP memory size.

One way to serve the file back is:

```
public function actionDownloadImage($id) {
    $model = UploadedImage::findOne($id);
    $stream =  fopen("data://image/jpeg;base64," .
                     base64_encode($model->contents->bin) );
    return \Yii::$app->response->sendStreamAsFile($stream)->send();
}
```

Comment: How do you convert this back for use in an <img> tag for example?

Comment: @GigaNova I added a simple method to do this in the reply. Your <img> tag should look like src="?r=controller/downloadImage&id=XYZ"